# SML: Sublime interpreter working incorrectly?

Tags: functional-programming, sublimetext3, sml, smlnj, sublimerepl

I am working on SML/NY project and I have a datatype `expression`:

```
datatype expression =  Constant of int |
        Variable of string |
        Operator of string * expression |
        Pair of expression list |
        List of expression list
```

I created a function that sum constants in expression (doesn't work for `List` yet):

```
fun cons [] = 0
    | cons (l) =
    case (hd l) of
        Constant a => (a + cons (tl l))
        | Operator ("*", Pair [Constant a, Constant b]) => (a*b + cons (tl l))
        | Operator ("*", List _) => (0 + cons (tl l))
        | _ => (0 + cons (tl l))
```

And now I'm building a function that join all `Constant` expressions in one:

```
fun joinSimilar (e:expression) =
    case e of
        Operator ("+", List (l)) => Operator ("+", List [
                                    Operator ("*",List [Constant (cons (l))])
                                    ])
        | _ => Constant 0
```

As far as I understand SML this seems as correct functions. But when I test:

```
joinSimilar(joinSimilar (Operator ("+", List [
    Constant 1,
    Operator ("*", Pair [Constant 3, Constant 1]),
    Operator ("*", Pair [Constant 5, Variable "x"]),
    Variable "x",
    Operator ("*", List [Variable "x", Constant 3]),
    Operator ("*", List [Variable "x", Variable "x"])])));
```

I get:

```
val it = Operator ("+",List [Operator ("*",List [Constant 0])]) : expression
```

which is not OK, because I should get `Constant 4`. The trick is, when I test only `cons` function

```
cons ([Constant 1,
    Operator ("*", Pair [Constant 3, Constant 1]),
    Operator ("*", Pair [Constant 5, Variable "x"]),
    Variable "x",
    Operator ("*", List [Variable "x", Constant 3]),
    Operator ("*", List [Variable "x", Variable "x"])]);
```

I get 4 and that is the right result. Why I get 0 in the first example?

Please help, I tried everything and my confusion is growing from minute to minute. Is that a problem of Sublime, which I am using?

Comment: The type seems odd. What does `Pair [Constant 1, Constant 2, Pair []]`represent? It's also very unclear what the purpose of those functions is, or why 4 is the correct result for that last one.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized what is wrong and this is like the most stupid mistake I've ever made. I wrote joinSimilar inside joinSimilar and this is wrong. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you for you best intentions.